# laravel im getting value in view table before 4day how to keep once get value show in table if date after any time

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

Using this code I'm able to get data before 4days in view table, I want to display once I get data it present show any time in view table

```
 $dueDate = Carbon::now()->addDays(4);
 Payment::select( 'next_due_date')->whereDate('next_due_date', $dueDate)->get();
```

Comment: What is your actual question? What have you tried already? Please [edit] your question and post any code you already have along with any errors you might get.

Comment: @brombeer im confused how to get it pls help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save the state you have many options.
Most convenient and fast ways are to save them in either `cache` or `database` itself.

#### Solution 1: saving in cache: (Receomented if you won't have too many rows in `payments` table)

```
$payments = Payment::select( 'next_due_date')
  ->where(function($q){
    // Get rows that are current next_due_date or is cached
    $q->whereDate('next_due_date', Carbon::now()->addDays(4))
      ->when(cache()->has('saved_payment_ids'), function(){
        $q->orWhereIn('id', cache()->get('saved_payment_ids') ?? []);
      });
  })
  ->get();

// Remember forever current rows in cache
cache()->forever('saved_payment_ids', $payments->pluck('id')->toArray());
```

#### Solution 2: saving in db (Receomented way)

```
/**
 * First you have to add boolean (tinyint) row in payments table
 * Lets call it: payment_due_date
 */
$payments = Payment::select( 'next_due_date')
  ->where(function($q){
    $q->whereDate('next_due_date', Carbon::now()->addDays(4))
      ->orWhere('payment_due_date', 1);
  })
  ->get();

// Update new rows to save for future fetching
Payment::query()
  ->where('payment_due_date', 0)
  ->whereDate('next_due_date', Carbon::now()->addDays(4))->update(['payment_due_date' => 1]);
```

Comment: in solution 2 // Update new rows to save for future fetching it auto updated or need to submit by form

Comment: It updates automaticaly. right next to select query runs update query. Try it

Comment: solution 2 some time it get worked some time not is there any other solution

Comment: It whould work everytime. `payment_due_date` column to default 0